# shell programming - how to properly pass variables within a function

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What's wrong with my bash script? I'm trying to pass positional parameters within a function.  My last test - `Test 4` works but its basically the command that I would run on the command line, no variable substitution.

I would like to call my function. Can someone tell me if the construction of my first 3 tests are valid and how to I can correct them? Thanks!

To execute: `./myscript.sh dev01 tester`

```
#!/bin/bash

set +x

if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
   echo "Usage: ./script.sh <ENV> <COMPONENT>"
   exit 1
fi

# Setup VARS
CREDS="-x foobar -a ec2.local_ipv4"
ENVIRONMENT="$1"
ROLES="$2"

function deploy {
    knife ssh "$CREDS" "chef_environment:"$ENVIRONMENT" AND roles:*"$ROLES"*" "uname"
}

echo "Test 1"
deploy

echo "Test 2"
DEPLOY=$(knife ssh "$CREDS" "chef_environment:"${ENVIRONMENT}" AND roles:*"${ROLES}"*" "uname")
$DEPLOY

echo "Test 3"
knife ssh "$CREDS" "chef_environment:"$ENVIRONMENT" AND roles:*"$ROLES"*" "uname"

echo "Test 4"
knife ssh -x foobar -a ec2.local_ipv4 "chef_environment:dev01 AND roles:*tester*" "uname"
```

Again, `Test 4` works only.

Comment: Consider making a habit of using `deploy() {` instead of `function deploy {` -- the former syntax works in any POSIX-compliant shell, whereas the latter depends on extensions and has no benefit to compensate for that lack of portability. And consider mklement0's note about all-uppercase variable names being in reserved space echoed.

Comment: ...back towards the topic of the immediate problem, btw, you might consider [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) additional reading (above and beyond the applicable, useful, and correct references given in said answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to using a *function*; it has to do with how you're storing arguments in a variable and using that variable later:

If you want to store *multiple* arguments in a (non-array) variable, you cannot *reference* that variable *double-quoted*, because the value is then passed as a *single* argument to the target utility.

An immediate fix would be to use `$CREDS` *unquoted*, but that makes the value subject to potentially unwanted [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), so the *robust* way to pass multiple arguments is to use an *array*:

```
# Store args. individually as array elements
CREDS=( '-x' 'foobar' '-a' 'ec2.local_ipv4' )

# ...

# "${CREDS[@]}" passes the elements of the array safely as *individual*
# arguments.
knife ssh "${CREDS[@]}" "chef_environment:$ENVIRONMENT AND roles:*$ROLES*" "uname"
```

Also note how I've embedded the `$ENVIRONMENT` and `$ROLES` variable references directly in the double-quoted string, which also makes the command more robust.

Finally, *it's better not to use all-uppercase shell-variable names* in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your clarity and detailed explanations! I appreciate the help.